# Get URL that msSaveBlob function generates in IE in a variable?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob, internet-explorer-11

I want to create a Blob object URL and not just download it, *msSaveBlob* just directly prompts the user for download, where as I require a function that will create and return a URL which I can use later in my code, just like what createObjectURL does, unfortunately which is not supported by IE 11.

My code snippet:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) //check if IE 11
{
   var url = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(Blob, "filename");// :(
}
else //Not IE 11 case
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(Blob); // returns a url of the blob object
```

Comment: Does anyone have anything to add to this, specifically on IE11?